# Best place to start finding out more background on the NDFD forecast?

Tags: metpy

My apologies for not asking a programming related question, but I'm not sure where else to start.  I have been making animation plots of the NDFD rainfall forecast, and I am noticing a lot of curious variations in the rainfall values along state boundaries.

This is making me think the NDFD is assembled from individual state or airport weather stations.  If I'm right, is there a way to obtain a state or station specific forecast via MetPy?

--Chris

Comment: NDFD is a mosaic product from the individual NWS Forecast Offices (WFOs) which often times have state borders as their bounds to their county warning areas.  https://www.ncei.noaa.gov/products/weather-climate-models/national-digital-forecast-database

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Regarding getting a specific forecast, there is not a way in MetPy, but you can use the [Siphon](https://unidata.github.io/siphon/) library to access a THREDDS Data Server, like the [demonstration one](https://thredds.ucar.edu) run by Unidata to get data like that. [This example notebook](https://github.com/Unidata/python-training/blob/master/pages/workshop/Model_Output/Downloading%20model%20fields%20with%20NCSS.ipynb) from Unidata's training materials shows how to get a profile for a single time from GFS. You would need to adapt the example to access the NDFD data rather than GFS, and change to request the time period of interest rather than a single time.